# I cannot get correct scale on bevel for nurbs curve

Tags: modeling

Im trying to get a 2mm bezier circle to bevel onto a curve .The circle is not appearing in the correct scale on the curve.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just seen your blend file and i've found why you get this problem (and how to fix it) :)

1. Select your curve
2. Edit mode
3. Select All vertices
4. In the properties tab (N key), change the Mean Radius value *(your actual value is 0.008)* to 1.

That's all ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!! Scale in edit mode from the beginning ( add bevel object first ).Dont use object mode for scaling!

Comment: You can scale in object mode, just remember to apply the transformations (Ctrl+A). See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation